Using as in @if syntax
I'm using Angular 18.1.0 with this syntax:
<div>
        @for(key of buildingKeys; track $index) {
        <ng-container *ngIf="buildingList[key][buildingLevel[key]] as build">
            <div>Name: {{build.name | i18n}}</div>
        </ng-container>
        }
    </div>

This works perfectly, I just don't feel like using <ng-container *ngIf="..."> syntax.
I was trying to achieve it using @if, however the syntax:
<div>
        @for(key of buildingKeys; track $index) {
            @if (buildingList[key][buildingLevel[key]] as build) {
                <div>Name: {{ build.name | i18n }}</div>
            }
        }
</div>

Gives me the following error:
Parser Error: Unexpected token 'as' at column 39 in [buildingList[key][buildingLevel[key]] as build]
My question is, is there a way to achieve it using the @if syntax?

I think you are missing ";" before as, it should be  @if (buildingList[key][buildingLevel[key]]; as build) {

Did you check the docs? https://angular.dev/api/core/@if But yes, @let is a clean solution too

If you're on version 18.1+, use @let like this:
@for(key of buildingKeys; track $index) {
    @let build = buildingList[key][buildingLevel[key]];
    @if (build) {
        <div>Name: {{ build.name | i18n }}</div>
    }
}

See https://angular.dev/api/core/@let
Note: @if ... ; as ... should also work. But @let is an elegant syntax.
